# can not change the text of my uilabel of customized cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My goal : click on the specific for of table view then will change the text of uilablel of this row

What I am doing is

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"click on row number %d",indexPath.row);
    NSIndexPath *index  =   [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
    NSArray     *array  =   [NSArray arrayWithObject:index];
    itemDesc.text       =   @"text should be changed";

    [shoppingListTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: array withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

And the xib is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuuAs.png)

However, after click on the row, the text of uilabel is still the same

Please advice me on this issue. Any comments are welcomed here

Comment: Where is your `itemDesc` declared as the `UILabel`?

Comment: what is the type of itemDesc? is a row or a uilabel itself? if its a row the you should try
    itemDesc.textLabel.text = @"text should be changed";

Comment: if you looked at the picture via a link I posted. It is declared in header file and it is the uilabel

Comment: try [itemDesc setText: @"text"];

Comment: why setText works and itemDesc.text not work at all

Answer (score 0):

when you use

```
[shoppingListTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: array withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

and the delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

will be used.